# How to change the TableView Cell row Height and font based on Settings in IOS Text View Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, font-size, uitableview

Hello I am building an application where I wanted to change the application font based on the settings from IOS. As given link below.

http://www.imore.com/how-increase-or-decrease-font-sizes-iphone-and-ipad-ios-7-dynamic-type

I wanted to know if there is anything that needs to be done.

Currently on changing the Text size to smallest or largest my application remains on the same font and hence the Table View cells , UI View screen labels remain as it is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Font you can use SystemFontSize to get current iOS font size. This link may useful to you which i followed - http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2013/Sep-25.html

Comment: Thanks Vinayk, I will try this. As of now we just using custom fonts so wanted to know if that is anything that we can apply with custom fonts changing using settings.